# how to send audio files to whatsapp using twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a media message with WhatsApp but I receive Error - 12300 Invalid Content-Type. I'm following the instructions from documentation but doesn't work. I'd sent successfully a lot of messages with images using the same code.

I'd sent successfully a lot of messages with images (jpg files) using the same code. I'd try with mp3, mp4, ogg and aac file types but not working.

```
function enviaQR(telefonoDestino) {
    twilioClient.messages
        .create({
            from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
            to: telefonoDestino,
            body: '¡Listo, ahora a cumplir tus sueños!',
            mediaUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxxdemo-99999.appspot.com/o/10999992_confirmacion.mp3?alt=media&type=audio&Content-Type=audio/mp3&token=d22c70ba-b123-4670-8a11-kljsdfy9sdcskl'
        })
        .then(message => {
            console.log(message.sid);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

This is the error message in Twilio console:

Error - 12300
Invalid Content-Type
Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL.
Please see the Twilio Markup XML Documentation for more information on valid Content-Types.

You must return a Content-Type for all requests. 
Requests without a Content-Type will appear in the Debugger as a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Possible Causes

Having a phone number, outgoing call request or action attribute refers to a non-XML or audio resource.

Having a Play verb attempt to play non-audio content, such as XML or text.

Possible Solutions
Verify that your web server is returning a Content-Type and it is the expected value
Make sure the URL noted refers to a valid resource

Message
Msg "Attempt to retrieve MediaUrl returned an unsupported Content-Type."

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your URL is working and containing less the 1MB file size audio.
2. .mp3 extension

   client.messages.create({
     from: twilioPhoneNumber,
     to: SenderNumber,
     body: messageBody,
   });

Example URL:

mediaUrl:"https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
mediaUrl:"http://crashtestdummy.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/crash-test-dummy-awards.jpg"
mediaUrl:"https://geekanddummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/central-locking-Ford-Mondeo-Mk-3.mp3"

Comment: Thank you Nikhil. I removed the parameters from URL but still not working. Twilio console show the same Error - 12300 Invalid Content-Type. The file size is 116kb. I tested the URL and Chrome reproduces the audio correctly when the URL include the parameters. The URLs tested: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xdemo-50264.appspot.com/o/x_confirmacion.mp3?alt=media&token=d22c70ba-b123-4670-8a11-4adef74b0699 --> tested ok from Chrome; https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xdemo-50264.appspot.com/o/x_confirmacion.mp3 --> Chrome show the file metadata but don't reproduce audio.

Comment: `{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not access bucket xdemo-50264.appspot.com",
    "status": "ACCESS_BUCKET"
  }
}`

Comment: Oh, they are not real URLs. These are: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/compartamosdemo-50264.appspot.com/o/10557652_confirmacion.mp3?alt=media&token=d22c70ba-b123-4670-8a11-4adef74b0699 and https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/compartamosdemo-50264.appspot.com/o/10557652_confirmacion.mp3

Comment: `{
  "name": "10557652_confirmacion.mp3",
  "bucket": "compartamosdemo-50264.appspot.com",
  "generation": "1560470063636152",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "audio/mp3",
  "timeCreated": "2019-06-13T23:54:23.636Z",
  "updated": "2019-06-13T23:54:23.636Z",
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "size": "118640",
  "md5Hash": "vY9RBdZF4CFHSjWNT9OW0w==",
  "contentEncoding": "identity",
 ...
}`  this is not audio

Comment: Hi, test the first url and it will play in a browser. I created other URL that don't need token but still not working. This is the new URL: http://190.117.64.198:19000/audiosdir/10557652_confirmacion.mp3